# Postgresql SUM function subtracting two columns is not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

I have a database with a column of id and another column of json data which contains information of name, timestamp, action, and place.

But the SUM function below doesn't work.

It just outputs a column with rows of endtime-starttime.
I was expecting the sum(endtime-starttime)
Please help.
Below is the code:

```
SELECT sum(extract (epoch from(endtime::timestamp - starttime::timestamp))/60)
FROM 
(select data->body->>timestamp as endtime, 
row_number() over (order by id) as row
from table
where data->body->>action='off')as endtable
inner join
(select data->body->>timestamp as starttime, 
row_number() over (order by id) as row
from table
where data->body->>action='on')as starttable
on endtable.row = starttable.row
group by endtable.row, starttable.row;
```

Comment: What does `SELECT count(*) ... group by endtable.row, starttable.row` return? If it returns all ones, then it means there is only one row in each `(endtable.row, starttable.row)` group. That would explain why the `sum` is the same as the difference. The sum of one value equals that value.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the group by? Assuming you expect 1 value as result.